# How to simplify the code using Apply Function

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

i have this script:

```
    library(plyr)
    library(gstat)
    library(sp) 
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
    a<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
    b<-c(15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105)
    x<-rep(a,3)
    y<-rep(b,3)
    E<-sample(30)
    freq<-rep(c(100,200,300),10)

    data<-data.frame(x,y,freq,E)
    data<-arrange(data,x,y,freq)

df <- ddply(data,"freq", function (h){
  dim_h<-length(h$x)
  perc_max <- 0.9
  perc_min <- 0.8
  u<-round((seq(perc_max,perc_min,by=-0.1))*dim_h)
  dim_u<-length(u)

  perc_punti<- percent(seq(perc_max,perc_min,by=-0.1))
  for (i in 1:dim_u)
  {  t<-u[i]
  time[i]<-system.time(
    for (j in 1:2)
    {  

      df_tass <- sample_n(h, t)

      df_residuo <- slice(h,-as.numeric(rownames(df_tass)))

      coordinates(df_tass)= ~x + y

      x.range <- range(h$x)  
      y.range <- range(h$y)
      grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 1), y = seq(from = y.range[1], 
                                                                                       to = y.range[2], by = 1))
      coordinates(grid) <- ~x + y
      gridded(grid) <- TRUE

      nearest = krige(E ~ 1, df_tass, grid, nmax = 1)

      nearest_df<-as.data.frame(nearest)
      names(nearest_df) <- c("x", "y", "E")
      #Error of prediction
      df_pred <- inner_join(nearest_df[1:3],select(df_residuo,x,y,E),by=c("x","y")) 
      names(df_pred) <- c("x", "y", "E_pred","E")
      sqm[j] <- mean((df_pred[,4]-df_pred[,3])^2)
    })[3]
  sqmm[i]<-mean(sqm)
  }
  df_finale<-data.frame(sqmm,time,perc_punti)
})
df
```

I measured in several points of coordinates (x,y) the value of the electromagnetic field (E value) at different frequencies (freq value). For each frequency value, I use once 90% of points and once 80% (with the for loop with l) to interpolate the value of the electromagnetic field (E) inside `grid` with Nearest Neighbour Interpolation (`krige` function); and i repeat this 2 times. The remaining points will then be used to calculate the prediction error. I hope it's clear.

This script above is a simplified case. Unfortunately, in my case the script takes too long for the two for-loops implemented. 
I want to ask if it's possible to simplify the code in some way, for instance by using the apply function family. Thanks.

**Reply** @clemlaflemme ok it works! thanks... now i have a little proble with the final dataframe, it looks like this:

```
  freq      1      2
1  100 121.00 338.00
2  100   0.47   0.85
3  200  81.00 462.50
4  200   0.74   0.73
5  300  36.00 234.00
6  300   0.82   0.76
```

but i want something like this:

```
  freq  sqmm time
1  100 121.0 0.47
2  100 338.0 0.85
3  200  81.0 0.74
4  200 462.5 0.73
5  300  36.0 0.82
6  300 234.0 0.76
```

how can i do that??

Comment: since your for loop is not recursive, you can use something like `df <- sapply(1:dim_u, function(i) { ... })`. Pay attention to what you write in the last line of `sapply` because this it what is stored in `df`

Comment: @clemlaflemme mmmh i don't understand where insert `sapply` function... you mean instead of the for loop `(i in 1:dim_u) ` ?

Comment: I should have written `df_final` instead of `df`. The main thing is that you are using a `for` loop to iterate over a variable, namely `i`. This can be done with `sapply` as I write above. Here you compute two variables, `sqmm` and `time`, so your `function(i) {` should end with `c(sqmm, time) }`

Comment: @clemlaflemme look above... i have a little problem with final dataframe ;)

Comment: The fact is `sapply` doesn't make any change to global variables. You should drop the `[i]` everywhere inside your loop for `time` and `sqmm`. Then I guess the output of `sapply` will be a matrix 2 rows `dim_u` columns.

Comment: To me more precise, instead of `for(i in ...) {` you write `df_final <- sapply(1:dim_u, function(i) {` you drop the `[i]` as mentioned above and change the bottom line of your loop as explained previously

Comment: @clemlaflemme ok!! thanks i solve my problem... however I noticed that by starting the script with a wider dataframe... the machine takes very long time to process... in your opinion there is something i can do with script structure? It can be lightened in any way? thanks!